# How to add attribute value of an element that only has siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario like this below:

```
<ul class="mainnav">
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="http://example.com">title</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="http://example.com">title</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to change href attribute value to "#" in **jQuery** for only navigation that has sub navigation.

For example

```
<ul class="mainnav">
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">title</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">title</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `li:has(ul) > a` to only select and manipulate only the `a` elements that are siblings of `ul` like so:

```
$('ul.mainnav > li:has(ul) > a').attr('href', '#');
```

```js
$('ul.mainnav > li:has(ul) > a').attr('href', '#');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainnav">
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="http://example.com">title</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="http://example.com">title</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).next('ul').find('a').length){
     $(this).attr('href','#')
  }
});
```

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).next('ul').find('a').length){
     $(this).css('color','red')
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainnav">
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">title</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">title</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">title</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achive this with a single selector:

```
$('a:not(:only-child)').attr('href','#')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the previous `a` sibling of `ul` descendants of `.mainnav`

```
$('.mainnav ul').prev('a').attr('href', '#')
```